# What is the second stiefel whitney class of SO(n)?

Tags: algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

$\omega_2(SO(n))=?$, that is, What is the second stiefel whitney class of  SO(n)?

Comment: What vector bundle did you have in mind?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$SO(n)$ is a Lie group and so its tangent bundle is trivial.  Thus $w_2(TSO(n)) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Furthermore, Is the Frame bundle of a spin manifold as a manifold spin?

Comment: @Boh Liu : You should ask this as a separate question, as it has little to do with the original one.